# Is passing just the length of the sides of a triangle, sufficient to draw a triangle in WebGL?

Tags: javascript, webgl

The question may not be clear, but I am gonna clear it here. Let's consider an array which have th co-ordinates of a triangle in clip space :

```
 var coor = [ 
   -0.4, 0.6, 
    0.0, -0.5, 
   -0.5, 0.0,  
    0.5, -0.5, 
    0.0 
 ]
```

So, the coor array will help us to draw a triangle using WebGL. But instead of it I want to go something like this :

```
var coor2 = [ 100, 100, 100 ]
```

In the coor2 I gave the measure of sides to draw a triangle. It will be an equilateral trinagle. So, can I do something such that I enter the three sides of a triangle and a script converts them to co-ordinate which can be cliped in the clip space and can be read by WebGL ?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: The lengths don't define the position in space o.O

Comment: @Andreas Yes I know that, but is there any way such that the lengths can be converted into co-ordinates which can be clipped in space ?

Comment: You can specify that the first corner is positioned in the point (0.0) in you 3D-space, and the second corner is also on the X-Axis. then you will have to points (0,0) - (100,0) - (50, sqrt( 10000 + 2500 )) in your triangle. I don't know anything about clip-spaces, but it seams as if the example coordinates you have shown a normalized to the maximum length of 1. If that's the case, you have to divide the coordinates by the maximum length = 100: (0,0) - (1,0)  - (0.5, sqrt(1.25))

Comment: Thanks, I was eagerly waiting for such mathematical answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebGL only cares that you set `gl_Position` to clip space values. It doesn't care how you do it.  It's up to you to decide how to do that. Inside the vertex shader, at least in WebGL1, things are stateless. Meaning when you draw a triangle your vertex shader will be called 3 times. It needs to set `gl_Position` to 3 different values in clipspace with no state between calls. So given 100 three times, how would you compute a **different** value each time your vertex shader is called?

Just imagine it in JavaScript

```
const gl_Position1 = vertexShader(100);
const gl_Position2 = vertexShader(100);
const gl_Position3 = vertexShader(100);
```

How is the function `vertexShader` supposed to produce 3 different values with no other input? Unless there is some other state it can't produce a different value. vertex shaders in WebGL1 don't have any other state.

You need to pass in some data that changes every iteration.

Of course you if the values changed then you could produce a triangle. Example

```
function vertexShader(v) {
  const angle = v / 3 * Math.PI * 2;
  return [Math.cos(angle), Math.sin(angle), 0, 1];
}

const gl_Position1 = vertexShader(0);
const gl_Position2 = vertexShader(1);
const gl_Position3 = vertexShader(2);
```

Would produce a triangle. Converting that to GLSL and WebGL

```js
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');

const vs = `
attribute float v;

#define PI radians(180.0)

void main() {
  float angle = v / 3.0 * PI * 2.0;
  gl_Position = vec4(cos(angle), sin(angle), 0, 1);
}
`;

const fs = `
precision mediump float;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
}
`;

const program = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs]);
const vLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'v');

const buf = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buf);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([0, 1, 2]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vLocation);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(vLocation, 1, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

gl.useProgram(program);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Of course given we only passed in [0, 1, 2] we can't easily specifiy a position but the point is at least now that we have a value that changes we can produce a triangle which is just to re-iterate *WebGL only cares that you set `gl_Position` to clip space values. It doesn't care how you do it.*

See [this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-drawing-without-data.html) for more